Unable to send message in client slack workspace by slack bot without adding bot creator to client workspace
I want to send a message to a client slack workspace member through a Slack bot.
The bot creator is not part of the client's Slack workspace. I used the sharable URL option to get access to the client workspace. After confirmation from the client's Slack admin, I received the bot token. I am using this token to send the message.
I set all the required scopes to send the message.
I am facing a weird issue: whenever I try to send a direct message (DM) to the client Slack members through the bot, it sends the message to its own DM instead.
For more information, I am able to list all the users of the client Slack workspace.
const webClient = new WebClient(
    "xoxb-bot token"
  );
  const conversationResponse = await webClient.conversations.open({
    users: "userID",
  });
  const messageResponse = await webClient.chat.postMessage({
    channel: conversationResponse.channel.id,
    text: "Hello from peakflo bot",
  });
 
Response  : 
 
messageResponse {
  ok: true,
  channel: 'D078RF47X4P',
  ts: '1719061250.486089',
  message: {
    user: 'U078ZD0KMFY',
    type: 'message',
    ts: '1719061250.486089',
    bot_id: 'B079625GN9Y',
    app_id: 'A079A5Y52F3',
    text: 'Hello from peakflo bot',
    team: 'T078UG9TAJH',
    bot_profile: {
      id: 'B079625GN9Y',
      app_id: 'A079A5Y52F3',
      name: 'peakflo_bot',
      icons: [Object],
      deleted: false,
      updated: 1719042406,
      team_id: 'T078UG9TAJH'
    },
    blocks: [ [Object] ]
  },
  response_metadata: {
    scopes: [
      'channels:join',
      'channels:read',
      'channels:write.invites',
      'chat:write',
      'files:write',
      'groups:read',
      'groups:write',
      'im:write',
      'mpim:write',
      'users:read',
      'im:read',
      'mpim:read',
      'users:read.email'
    ],
    acceptedScopes: [ 'chat:write' ]
  }
}

i am trying to send the message on client slack workspace without adding bot creator to client workspace
